# How did Voyager 1 avoid crashing into Jupiter?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, jupiter, voyager

Consider the following video (taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:790106-0203_Voyager_58M_to_31M_reduced.gif)):

[image: Voyager approach to Jupiter]

To me it looks like Voyager 1 will crash into Jupiter. Obviously Voyager 1 didn't crash into Jupiter, but at a glance it looks like it will.

What exactly is happening in that video/animation? How did it avoid crashing? I'm assuming the spacecraft didn't have enough fuel to perform a burn to insert itself into orbit, but maybe it executed a burn to slingshot around it?

Comment: @Ruslan nice edit!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Voyager was continually pointing its camera towards Jupiter, while passing alongside it, with its closest approach being 349,000 km. With no visible fixed references behind the planet, it's not obvious that the camera direction is changing during the approach.

Comment: The exposures were carefully timed as well, further removing any perception that the Voyager is going around Jupiter: From the "alternative text for image:" [animated view of planet getting larger. These pictures were taken every 10 hours over 28 days in 1979; each frame shows Jupiter at the same local time with the Great Red Spot appearing stationary within its cloud belt while clouds move right to left past it; other cloud belts move left to right.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:790106-0203_Voyager_58M_to_31M_reduced.gif).

Comment: (for the reference, 10 hours is the Jupiter day length, so the Great Red Spot has just completed a roundtrip around Jupiter and is back where it was 10h ago.)